# Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

Getting error when I pass more then 2400 items.

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in
>   this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.

How to solve this? My code is as below:

```
using (var dc = new DataContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
{
    products = dc.Products.Where(x => productIds.Contains(x.product_id)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You Can go do manual sql and use table value parameters. This Will remove the 2100 entry limitation which (is a weird thing in sql by the way) :)

Comment: You can also pass a XML or JSON string as a parameter and shred it in your query. It may also require writing manual query.

Comment: You can write a manual query and use a table valued parameter or XML or JSON. If you want it to be performant that is the way I would go. Or you can use the link from the marked duplicate.